# Dart: transform a list into a number of occurrences list but only the neigbors together

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw examples on how to do kind of similar stuff but never exactly what I want, I'm wondering how to do it properly so if you can give me an hint I would be really happy ! :)

`["a","a","b","a","c","c","b","b","b","d","a"] =====> [2,1,1,2,3,1,1]`

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use a "built-in" `splitBetween` method from [IterableExtension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension.html):

```
final someList = ["a","a","b","a","c","c","b","b","b","d","a"];
final counts = someList.splitBetween((a, b) => a != b).map((a) => a.length);
print(counts);
```

you can use the following:

```
extension CountAdjacentExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<int> countAdjacent() sync* {
    var iterator = this.iterator;
    if (!iterator.moveNext()) return;
    var previous = iterator.current;
    var cnt = 1;
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      var element = iterator.current;
      if (previous != element) {
        yield cnt;
        cnt = 0; // it's gonna be incremented right below to 1
      }
      cnt++;
      previous = element;
    }
    yield cnt;
  }
}
```

the usage is:

```
final someList = ["a","a","b","a","c","c","b","b","b","d","a"];
print(someList.countAdjacent());
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the collection package

##### Dart Setup

I'have create a new dart app  for testing the code. In the app folder create the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```yaml
name: data_collection_app
description: A example of using the collection librarry.
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.16.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies: 
  collection: ^1.16.0
```

```dart
$ dart pub add collection
```

#### Flutter setup

If your are using flutter

```
$ flutter pub add collection
```

#### Usage

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // Import the package

final data = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "d", "a"];

void main() {
  var foo = data.splitBetween((a, b) => a != b).map((a) => a.length); // Use splitBetween method
  print(foo);
}
```

Output

```dart
(2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1)
```